# Paste from clipboard into CtrlP input in GVim

Tags: gvim, plugin-ctrlp

Using CtrlP with **GVim** I often need to open a file with the name from the system clipboard (on Windows). So my workflow should be:

- <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd>
- {somehow paste name from the clipboard}
- Select file and open it

In the CtrlP input line I tried:

- <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> - it didn't work. <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> is remapped by CtrlP.
- <kbd>Ctrl+Ins</kbd> it inserts `"+P`

The equivalent without CtrlP plugin would be:

`:e` **/<kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>

So my question is, how can I paste into the CtrlP input line from the system clipboard?

*Note:* This is not a problem, if using vim within the console, where proprietary coping and pasting is implemented.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can paste from any register (including the clipboard) into CtrlP, as explained in `:help ctrlp-pasting`:

```
  <Insert>,                                                   *'ctrlp-pasting'*
  <MiddleMouse>
    Paste the clipboard content into the prompt.

  <c-\>
    Open a console dialog to paste <cword>, <cfile>, the content of the search
    register, the last visual selection, the clipboard or any register into the
    prompt.

Choose your own mappings with |g:ctrlp_prompt_mappings|.
```

Using the default mappings you should type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> followed by <kbd>c</kbd> (the 'c' appears on the input prompt for clipboard).

Another options are to use the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key or the middle mouse button.